# Spring boot POM file add dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to add dependency in my pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat.embed.jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <version>10.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

But getting an error Missing artifact org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat.embed.jasper:jar:10.1.3

Tried to make changes but still getting same error

Comment: [Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the desired behavior, **a specific** problem or **error** and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Try a valid version of your artifact, like one from the list here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper

Answer (score 2):

I checked maven central for your dependency . version 10.1.3 is not found .
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper